# Emacs stops responding when I run run-octave

Tags: emacs

When I try to use Octave via M-x run-octave Emacs stops responding and I have to force-close it. Why can this be happning?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think that the people from Emacs church over here will gladly help you, but try to provide a bit more information, such as you OS, emacs version, Octave version. Tbh I don't even know how to install whatever needs to be installed to make `M-x run-octave` available in my Emacs.

Comment: I got a workaround by  opening a shell and running octave on it, but in case anyone can identify the problem I use Ubuntu 14, Emacs 24 and Octave 3.8.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I'm using slackware 14.1, emacs 24.3.1, octave 3.8.1.
Octave-mode is part of Emacs (since version 19.35).

I came across [this post](https://gist.github.com/gspe/b4396dc8faef91d57441), which seems to work for me.

Try adding the file .octaverc to your home directory containing only the line

```
PS1(">> ")
```

[This Discussion](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Emacs-freeze-td1625464.html) sounds like the same issue, and it may have to do with detecting the octave prompt.